# Uses of method BinarySearch with ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist, indexof

In C# we have ArrayList to store various type of data and objects.

In ArrayList we have IndexOf method which returns the index of first occurrence with in the ArrayLIst.

Also in ArrayList we have BinarySearch method which searches the Sorted ArrayList for an element and returns it's index.

My query : 
To my understanding BinarySearch and IndexOf are doing same task.In what scenario will BinarySearch method be useful ? I understand that BinarySearch needs a sorted ArrayList .So can we say that when ArrayList is sorted one should use BinarySearch and when not sorted we should use IndexOf method ? Also in Sorted ArrayList which method gives high performance : BinarySearch or IndexOf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definitions**

`BinarySearch` works by progressively halving the size of the search space. It relies on the data first being *ordered by the search parameter* to accomplish this. Its performance is logarithmic - O(log n)

`IndexOf` will perform a *linear search* to find the index of the item - O(n).

**Consequences**

This effectively means that in an `ArrayList` of 1000 values, where the item being sought is at the end of the list, `IndexOf` would have to examine 1000 values to find the result. `BinarySearch` would first check the middle value, then the middle of the remaining values and so on, effectively only examining 10 items in total before returning the correct result.

Of course, *in practice* it is unlikely that the sought item will always be at the end of the list, so 1000 comparisons is only the *worst-case scenario* for a linear search. If the item were the first one in the list, `IndexOf` would out-perform `BinarySearch`.

**As with all algorithms, which to use depends heavily on what you are trying to accomplish and the nature of your data.**

If your data is unsorted and you do not want to change the order of the items in your `ArrayList`, or if comparing data is an expensive operation, `BinarySearch` could be far more computationally expensive than `IndexOf` despite performing fewer comparisons on average due to the need to make a copy of the `ArrayList` and sort that copy.

If the item you need to find generally tends to be one of the first items in your `ArrayList` (on average) then `IndexOf` would probably be the best option to use.

Similarly if you have a very small array (in the order of 10 items), `BinarySearch` will not yield significantly better results.

Code relying on `BinarySearch` may also be more difficult to maintain - Your code must document the fact that maintaining ordering of the data is essential to the correct performance of the application - otherwise another developer might later alter the code to something that re-orders the data invalidating the binary search and breaking the application.

If your data is already sorted, (ie. it doesn't need to be sorted just to make it ordered for the purposes of searching), then a `BinarySearch` will almost always outperform `IndexOf` when searching for an item in a list of more than a handful of values... But the level of performance gain might be completely insignificant in an application that is also performing any other non-trivial tasks (such as I/O bound activities).

**Recommendation**

In general, one should favour the simpler operation which has no requirements or side-effects (ie. `IndexOf`) until it becomes apparent (through profiling) that `BinarySearch` would *significantly improve* the application's usability or efficiency.

Whenever you choose an algorithm, always document the reason why. It will help other developers understand the code, and sometimes that "other" developer will be you, reviewing code years after you've forgotten why you chose one algorithm over another in the first place.

Comment: thanks pal for detailed answer , I really appreciate your efforts in doing detailing of which one to use when.

Comment: your answer has arose few more queries in my mind, hope my queries are reaching to you as due to some unknown reason i'm not able to mention your user name @MATT here. my query 1 => If our ArrayList is having elements in already sorted order and now someone attempt to add new element into this, now how to maintain the sorted characteristic? and this is always to be worried about while adding new element always.

Comment: Query 2 => if ArrayList is not already sorted and I want to sort it , but it contains objects with some ID property , on Id i want sorting .I got something related qry which talks about implementing IComparable interface to class, is that all? will it solve my problem ? or some more to do ?

Comment: _If you have new questions, please create a new question rather than follow up with questions in comments_. To maintain sorted order on an `ArrayList`, either perform a `Sort` after every insert or append operation, or compute where an item ought to be inserted prior to inserting it (using `BinarySearch` for example). The second option is probably more efficient. Depending on your application, you may find you do not need to maintain sorted order after every insert, and could sort only when you need to (ie. if you don't need to search often, you could sort only prior to a search).

Comment: To perform `Sort` on an `ArrayList` of Class instances, you will need to implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) for your Class. In your example of having a `Class` that has an `id` property, implement your comparison in terms of the id.